# How to conditionally replace values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe (Python 3.7) and I want to conditionally replace some values of column 'XX'. My dataframe looks like this

```
      XX        Date      Time
0      0  2016-05-01  19:00:00
1      1  2016-05-01  18:00:00
2      3  2016-05-01  17:00:00
3     -1  2016-05-01  16:00:00
4      5  2016-05-01  15:00:00
5      7  2016-05-01  14:00:00
6     -1  2016-05-01  13:00:00
7      6  2016-05-01  12:00:00
```

My logic is this,

```
if df.value ==-1 AND df.Time == '16:00:00':
    df.value = 2
```

However, I have a dictionary of lookup values to map the replacement values.

```
lookup_dict = {'01:00:00':1, '02:00:00':4 , ...., '23:00:00':0}
```

This is the end result I'm hoping to achieve.

```
      XX        Date      Time
0      0  2016-05-01  19:00:00
1      1  2016-05-01  18:00:00
2      3  2016-05-01  17:00:00
3      2  2016-05-01  16:00:00
4      5  2016-05-01  15:00:00
5      7  2016-05-01  14:00:00
6      1  2016-05-01  13:00:00
7      6  2016-05-01  12:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) only for values filtered by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#added values for match
lookup_dict = {'13:00:00':1, '16:00:00':2, '23:00:00':0}

m = df['XX'] == -1
df.loc[m, 'XX'] = df.loc[m, 'Time'].map(lookup_dict)
print (df)
   XX        Date      Time
0   0  2016-05-01  19:00:00
1   1  2016-05-01  18:00:00
2   3  2016-05-01  17:00:00
3   2  2016-05-01  16:00:00
4   5  2016-05-01  15:00:00
5   7  2016-05-01  14:00:00
6   1  2016-05-01  13:00:00
7   6  2016-05-01  12:00:00
```